# Python Anaconda error "avconv/avprobe not found in path"

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda, avconv

I am trying to run a Machine Learning package that I got from my friend. I am following his instructions on installing Anaconda on my Ubuntu 16.04, required libraries, etc. But I still have issues running it. What is the problem?

I'm simply running a script: `home/anaconda3/python address/to/myscript`. I'm not a python guy. But I simply did `pip install sk-video` if this is related to this package. He also said I need to do the same for `librosa`, `opencv`, and `imageio` which I did.

```
/home/smh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skvideo/__init__.py:356: UserWarning: avconv/avprobe not found in path: 
  warnings.warn("avconv/avprobe not found in path: " + str(path), UserWarning)

 1 -th video being processed, ts/Nadal_new3.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smh/Desktop/mmt/Detection_module/detection_main.py", line 21, in <module>
    Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.metadata_creation(cur_video_name)
  File "/home/smh/Desktop/mmt/Detection_module/Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.py", line 105, in metadata_creation
    final_label_list, pred_labels_list= label_prediction( mfcc_list, num_frames= 3)
  File "/home/smh/Desktop/mmt/Detection_module/Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.py", line 28, in label_prediction
    clf_trained = joblib.load('/home/smh/Desktop/mmt/Detection_module/trainsvm_mfcc.pkl') 
  File "/home/smh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/smh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1039, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/home/smh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/home/smh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
    return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.externals.joblib.numpy_pickle' has no attribute 'NumpyArrayWrapper'
```

Comment: What did you run? Does it fail on package installation or when you run some script?

Comment: on running a script: `home/anaconda3/python address/to/myscript`

Comment: Try `env PATH=$PATH:home/anaconda3/bin home/anaconda3/bin/python address/to/myscript` it might help in case if you didn't add anaconda PATH to bashrc

Comment: Same error. No difference.